# How do i achieve this cool footer effect?

Tags: html, css

I found a cool website that uses alot of effects that i would like to replicate but put my own spin on: http://www.loicnottet.com/#Tour

If you scroll down to the bottom there is a footer, and it appears from under the body of the website as you scroll.
I have tried to replicate this effect but can't work out how to do it, also i kind find any resources that show the same effect.

How would i achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Good questions have a clear problem statement, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and a detailed explanation of what you tried and what went wrong. Links to external websites are not enough and will inevitably change, rendering your question unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the element and see what they did. It's pretty self explanatory. They fixed the footer and added a div at the end of the page that's the same height as the footer but the background is transparent.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. I did inspect it but couldn't tell how they did it haha...